# Iframe,embed and object tag's are not working with Universal windows app(UWP)?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-iot-core, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10, windows-community-toolkit

```
<iframe src="C:\Users\sajith1x\Desktop\1.1.18\test1.html"></iframe> 

<embed src="C:\Users\sajith1x\Desktop\1.1.18\test1.html" width="600" height="400"> </embed>

<object type="text/html" data="C:\Users\sajith1x\Desktop\1.1.18\test1.html"></object>
```

My requirement is that to load dynamically created html file inside a popup, I tried iframe,object and embed tag's all three are working with ie and chrome browsers but not working with UWA(Instead of data in that html page its showing blank).suggest some solution for this.

Comment: why do you need an iframe or embed?

Comment: is any other way to show the same.I found only this as solution if any thing else kindly share and help

Comment: Is this a UWP question or a Windows 10 IoT Core question?

Comment: our requirement is to develop UWA to run in windows 10 IOT platform.

Answer (score 0):

**If your dynamically created HTML file is not in the app related folders**, for example, DocumentsLibrary, you can read it first and use NavigateToString() to display it. To support access HTML file you need to add file type association like this:

[image]

Here is a C# sample:

```
        var file = await KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.GetFileAsync("test1.html");
        var content = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        ulong size = content.Size;
        using (var inputStream = content.GetInputStreamAt(0))
        {
            using (var dataReader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(inputStream))
            {
                uint numBytesLoaded = await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)size);
                htmlContent = dataReader.ReadString(numBytesLoaded);
            }
        }

        try
        {
            webView1.NavigateToString(htmlContent);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

**If your dynamically created HTML file is in the app installed folder** you can do it like this:

[image]

On Windows 10 IoT Core, if you want to access C drive like "C:\" you need [Set folder permissions for UWP apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/commandlineutils). **Note this will work only with native Win32 apis for eg. CreateFile2 and not with WinRT apis like StorageFolder, StorageFile etc.**